# Unable to bulk upload log data in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb, bigdata, nosql

I need to bulk upload the log data in ArangoDB. It is not in JSON and CSV format, its a log data in gz format.

> 203.109.94.55 - - [19/Jun/2015:16:02:45 +0000] "GET /origin-cdn.firstcry.com/brainbees/images/products/thumb/506739a.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 21514 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; XT1022 Build/KXC21.5-40) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.114 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
>   183.87.73.202 - - [19/Jun/2015:16:02:45 +0000] "GET /origin-cdn.firstcry.com/brainbees/images/products/bigthumb/555258a.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 34903 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0.2; AO5510 Build/LRX22G)" "-"
>   183.87.73.202 - - [19/Jun/2015:16:02:45 +0000] "GET /origin-cdn.firstcry.com/brainbees/images/products/bigthumb/555401a.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 32334 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0.2; AO5510 Build/LRX22G)" "-"

Even when we are trying for uploading single file through Arangosh then too it is not uploading and generating error that format is invalid.
I have daily data of 2 GB to upload and process, how can I do through ArangoDB?
As I have gone through documents of ArangoDB and found the bulk upload for only JSON. Any help with how to upload and process the same will be grateful?

Answer (score 3):

ArangoDB only supports bulk upload of JSON, CSV, or TSV. Therefore you need to convert the log file. I good starting point is google. For example, there is a project called "log2json":

```
https://github.com/kadnan/logs2json
```

with some minor tweaks you should be able to generate lines of JSON (the above project creates one large JSON, which is not what you want).